# Rendering a list inside another and using variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, v-for

I want to render 2 list one nested inside another but I can't use the variable of parent list inside the nested one. Where do I do the mistake here?

```
<v-card
        v-for="n in lengthI"
.
.
<v-card
        v-for="image in images.n"
```

my images object,

```
images:{one:[{flex: 12, src:'https://i.ibb.co/mHNXycQ/Filler.png', title:'kuzey cephe'}, {flex: 6, src:'https://i.ibb.co/QYvByD3/cephe.png', title:'güney cephe'}, {flex: 6, src:'https://i.ibb.co/QYvByD3/cephe.png', title:'batı cephe'}], two:[{flex: 12, src:'https://i.ibb.co/mHNXycQ/Filler.png', title:'kuzey cephe'}, {flex: 6, src:'https://i.ibb.co/QYvByD3/cephe.png', title:'güney cephe'}, {flex: 6, src:'https://i.ibb.co/QYvByD3/cephe.png', title:'batı cephe'}], three:[{flex: 12, src:'https://i.ibb.co/mHNXycQ/Filler.png', title:'kuzey cephe'}, {flex: 6, src:'https://i.ibb.co/QYvByD3/cephe.png', title:'güney cephe'}, {flex: 6, src:'https://i.ibb.co/QYvByD3/cephe.png', title:'batı cephe'}]}
```

Comment: Replace `images.n` with `n.images`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting lists is pretty straightforward in that variable names need to be unique and be sure to assign a `key` attribute for each:

```
<v-card v-for="(n, i) in items" :key="'item' + i">
  <v-card v-for="(image, k) in n.images" :key="'image' + k">

     // do stuff here

  </v-card>
</v-card>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no, the problem is not the key, its, I can't use "images.n" in nested loop this does not work and I cant understand why

Comment: Because `images.n` is backwards, it's `n.images`

Comment: Also, what is `lengthI` supposed to be? Is it an array or an integer?

Comment: Thanks, I know my mistake now I will try and make it work.